# Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe (shared folder on VBOX 6.0 and Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtual-machine

i've some troubles making requests in my new laravel-project in my ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine (hosted by windows). The project is running in `/media/sf_project` folder, i've already set my apache2.conf that contains currently this:

apache2.conf

```
<Directory /media/sf_nar>
    Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

I've already set `chmod -R 777` to the folder and added the group user to `/etc/groups` obtaining `vboxsf:x:114:batsi,www-data`, i've set also the owning of the file via `chow -R user` but with no effect.

when i "ll" the `/media` folder the output is the following:

```
batsi@batsi:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ll /media
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root   4096 Mar 12 12:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root   4096 Mar  6 13:20 ../
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 8192 Mar 12 13:46 sf_nar/
```

What could i do now?